# Como remover o Node no Arch linux / Linux Manjaro

Tags: node.js, linux, terminal

Recentemente iniciei um projeto porém o meu node está com um pequeno erro e preciso remove-lo. A seguinte dúvida é como remover completamente o node.js usando o terminal do Arch-linux ?

E ao executar o comando pacman -R node como super usuário me aparece esse erro:

```
erro: não foi possível abrir o arquivo /var/lib/pacman/local/firefox-58.0.2-1.1/desc: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado erro:alvo não encontrado: node
```

Comment: Não seria algo como `pacman -R node`?

Comment: Não, eu tentei por este e não deu certo. lembro que quando eu instalei o node eu executei assim sudo npm install nodejs

Comment: Você usou um gerenciador de pacotes, que depende do Node, para instalar o Node? Estranho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente fazer a reinstalação usando seu gerenciador de pacotes. No meu caso, eu uso o 'yay':

```
yay -S nodejs
```

O gerenciador de pacotes vai perguntar se deseja sobrescrever. Uma outra solução seria instalar uma versão menor (LTS) e colocar a última novamente.

```
yay -S nodejs-lts-carbon
```

Quando perguntar se deseja remover, aperte S.

Feito isso, volte a instalar o Node v10+.

```
yay -S nodejs
```

Espero que ajude!